# Need some help to make multiple images clickable disabled and disappear after 10 clicks

Tags: javascript, count, onclick, counter

I have three images that i need to be disabled and disappear after 10 clicks, so far i have made them clickable and made it so i get resources from them.

Maybe i should be using parameter? for the function also?

```js
tree1.onclick = harvestTree;
tree2.onclick = harvestTree;
tree3.onclick = harvestTree;

function harvestTree() {
  var woodAmount = 25;
  wood = wood + woodAmount;
  outputAmount.innerHTML += `<p><li>Hugget tre, fikk 25 treressurser</li></p>`;
  infoBar();
}
```

Comment: `disabled` or `disappear` that's not the same thing.

Comment: Changed it to include both. Since i want the tree to disappear e.g opacity 0, but also make it so you can no longer get resources by continue clicking where the object is hidden.

Comment: what is `tree1`, `tree2` and `tree3` elements ? what does this have to do with your question? what does the `harvestTree()` function do in this story !

Comment: tree1 - 3 is images of a tree which is clickable and you get 25 wood, when clicking them. harvestTree is just what i decided to call the function for commands.